# How to get specific value using from jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using jquery ajax function for getting some value and submitting some values, so far I have no issue for submitting value but when it comes to collect the value it is showing the old value not the new one.

I know a method where we can define json object and pick value from there, if you are working on the single same page.

But I want to know is there any other way around we can use to get the specific value.

```
(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bmup").click(function(){
        var upval = $.post(window.location,{rate:$("#bvup").val()},function(data){
            alert(data);
            $("#bmup").html(data);
        });
    });
    });
```

the data returning here is full html of the whole website, while I want only the data of rate, the updated value of rate variable that is defined in php.

In case if it helps:
the function is updating +1 in db and updating the value of rate after updating but that value is showing after the page refresh, so I thought to implement jquery & ajax now the problem is the returning data is full html of my whole website, not just the rate variable.

Ok sorry this is the edited version I thought only jquery will enough but here we go with the full situation.

i am using this on single.php on wordpress
So there are already many html marked ups and echo's before my $rate.
when I am trying to get rate variable it is printing my whole page instead.

```
<?php 
 /**
 * Singular Content Template
 */

?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php $cuser = wp_get_current_user(); ?>

<div class="main wrap cf">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 main-content">

            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php 

                    $panels = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'panels_data', true);

                    if (!empty($panels) && !empty($panels['grid'])):

                        get_template_part('content', 'builder');

                    else:

                        get_template_part('content', 'single');

                    endif; 
                ?>
                <div class="comments">
<div class="cntt">

<?php

//if(!isset($_COOKIE['rate'])) {

    if($_POST['rate']=='up') {
    $rate=get_post_meta($post->ID,'up',true);
    $rate=$rate+1;
    update_post_meta($post->ID,'up',$rate);
    setcookie(rate, 1, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
    }

    if($_POST['rate']=='down') {
    $rate=get_post_meta($post->ID,'down',true);
    $rate=$rate+1;
    update_post_meta($post->ID,'down',$rate);
    setcookie(rate, 1, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
    }

if(isset($_COOKIE['rate'])) {
    echo "<div class='errormainbtn'> Only one vote is allowed ! </div>";
    }

}


$totalup = get_post_meta($post->ID,'up',true);
$totaldn = get_post_meta($post->ID,'down',true);

?>

<input type='hidden' id='valval' value='<?php echo $rate; ?>' />

<div class="bothmainbtn">
<div class="btmainup">
<form method='POST' action="">
<input id="bvup" type=hidden name=rate value=down>
<input id="bmup2" class="tpbtn" type="submit" value= 
'<?php 

if ($totaldn != "" && $totaldn != 0) {
echo "Disagree:&nbsp;" . $totaldn;
}
else
{
echo "Disagree ?";
}
?>'
>
</form>
<div id="bmup">Click</div>
</div>



<div class="btmaindown">
<form method='POST' action="">
<input type=hidden name=rate value=up>
<input class="tpbtn" type=submit value=
'<?php 
if ($totalup != "" && $totalup != 0) {
echo "Agree:&nbsp;".$totalup;
}
else
{
echo "Agree ?";
}
?>'
>
</form>
</div>
</div>

<?php include 'leftsiderev.php';?>
<?php include 'rightsiderev.php';?>



<!-- Main working sheet -->







                </div> <!-- comment-->

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </div>

        <?php Bunyad::core()->theme_sidebar(); ?>

    </div> <!-- .row -->
</div> <!-- .main -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

What i am trying to achieve is when the user click on vote up or down, the $totaldn will have the new value I want to show this updated value.

as if I want to implement the json object I have to use array and then I will have to use it on top of the page, while this is quite difficult in word press as header's are already passed with navigation's.

any solution ?

Comment: Is there any error on the server log?

Comment: `$("#bmup").html(data.find('#bvup').val());` try this.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you

```
<?php 
         $rate = getRate(); // grabs the rate
         if($_POST) {

          echo $rate;

         }else { // if it is not post show the html

        ?>

        <html>
         <title></title>
         <body>
           // content goes here
         </body>
        </html>
        <?php 
        }
 ?>
```